# Helm chooses unreadable highlight colors in solarized-dark

Tags: emacs, color-scheme, emacs-helm

I'm experimenting with helm, after using icicles for a long time.

I used the popular solarized-dark colour scheme by default most of the time, and helm seems to be choosing particularly unreadable colors:

[image: bad sol-dark colours in helm]

...how can I advise helm to select more useful colors? Hopefully so it works well when I switch to solarized-light as well.

Comment: Why not report a bug to the maintainers of this color theme?

Comment: is it a colour scheme bug? or a helm bug? or an emacs bug? or a life bug?

Comment: It is obviously a shortcoming of the color theme, which fails to address Helm faces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I first tried the solarized theme, I had a similar problem with `helm` menus as shown above. The highlighting on `diff` and `magit` were even worse.

[image]

I started to try to fix this myself but I eventually realized that there are at least three different versions of the solarized theme currently in MELPA. The one called `solarized-theme` is the one you want. The helm selection bar is very subtle and underlined, like below.

[image]

Comment: I came to the same conclusion a few days ago, and have been happy since. Tick for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try `M-x customize-group RET helm` from there you can customize `Helm Selection face` and other helm faces.

Comment: This is one solution, but the real solution is to add the faces to your theme and send a Pull-request to the maintainer.

Comment: A specific solution which I use in my emacs.d (for one of the Tomorrow themes):

`(set-face-attribute 'helm-selection nil :background "#441100")`

Comment: Wow. The interactive face editing in Emacs is really impressive and easy to use.